# The $\sigma$-algebra generated by $f^{-1}\mathcal{Z}$, where $\mathcal{Z}$ generates $\mathcal{A}$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Is the following statement true?

> Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a function and $\mathcal{Z}\subset Y$ be the
>   subset generating the sigma algebra $\mathcal{A}$. Then
>   $f^{-1}A:=\{f^{-1}A:A\in\mathcal{A}\}$ is the smallest sigma algebra
>   generated by $f^{-1}\mathcal{Z}:=\{f^{-1}Z:Z\in\mathcal{Z}\}$

My attempt is as follows:

By contradiction, say $\mathcal{A}'$ is the smallest sigma algebra generated by $f^{-1}\mathcal{Z}$

$$f^{-1}\mathcal{Z}\subset\mathcal{A}'$$
$$\mathcal{A}'\quad \sigma\text{-algebra in } X \implies\{F\subset Y:f^{-1}F\in\mathcal{A}'\}\text{ is a sigma algebra in Y}$$

Now $\mathcal{Z}\subset \{F\subset Y:f^{-1}F\in\mathcal{A}'\}$ and $\mathcal{Z}\subset\mathcal{A}$.

This implies that $\mathcal{A}\subset \{F\subset Y:f^{-1}F\in\mathcal{A}'\}$ since $\mathcal{A}$ is the smallest sigma algebra containing $\mathcal{Z}$

I got stuck here. Am I on the right track? And is the statement true in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are on the right track.

So you have $\mathcal{A}\subset \{F\subset Y:f^{-1}F\in\mathcal{A}'\}$. This means that $f^{-1}\mathcal A\subset\mathcal A'$.

Conversely, since $\mathcal Z\subset\mathcal  A$, we clearly have $f^{-1}\mathcal Z\subset f^{-1}\mathcal A$. Since $f^{-1}\mathcal A$ is a sigma algebra and $\mathcal A'$ is the smallest sigma algebra which contains $f^{-1}\mathcal Z$, we have $\mathcal A'\subset f^{-1}\mathcal A$.

You just showed that $f^{-1}\mathcal A\subset\mathcal A'\subset f^{-1}\mathcal A$. Therefore, $f^{-1}\mathcal A=\mathcal A'$.

The statement is true.

PS : There is no need to say "By contradiction" in the beginning since the proof is "direct".